# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException accesing subclass in JSF 2.2 and RichFaces

Tags: richfaces, el, jsf-2.2

I have the next component in JSF:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable value="#{userList}" var="obj" id="table">
    <c:forEach items="#{columns}" var="column">
        <rich:column width="#{column.width}">
                <h:outputText value="#{obj[column.property]}"/>
        </rich:column>
    </c:forEach>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

This table paints the columns of the object User.java, and receives which columns I want to paint in a List

**User.java**

```
String name;
UserType type;
// More attributes

// All these methods are properly implemented
public void setName(String name);
public void setType(UserType type);
public String getName();
public UserType getType();
```

**MyBean.java**

In my bean I initialized the next ArrayList with the columns, and I get a list of users from the database.

```
// Columns
List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
columns.add(new Column("100", "name")); // String width, String property
columns.add(new Column("100", "type.name")); // String width, String property
// More columns

// Users
List<User> userList = db.getUsers();
```

This code is working properly if I dont add the second column of the previous code. If I do then I get the next exception:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'my.package.User' does not have the property 'type.name'.
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:661)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:290)
```

**Question:**

How can I access the property "name" of the subclass "UserType"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `public String getTypeName()` would seem to be easiest.

You're telling the outputText to look for property with the name `type.name`, it's a String.